# Hibernate PropertyAccessException During OneToOne Mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have four entities `RoomNight`, `BookingCorporateDetails`,  `BookingDiscountDetails` and  `BookingDetails` in which `BookingCorporateDetails`,  `BookingDiscountDetails` and  `BookingDetails` refers to `RoomNight` on column (`room_night_booking_id`).

I am trying to create a Foreign key join on the `BookingCorporateDetails`,  `BookingDiscountDetails` and  `BookingDetails` in order to save/get/delete all data together. I am able to save the data into Database but when I try to retrieve I get Hibernate PropertyAccessException. The entity table structure is -

**AbstractJpaEntity.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class AbstractJpaEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  protected Long id;

  @Column(name = "created_at")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  protected Date createdAt;

  @Column(name = "created_by", length = 32, nullable = true)
  protected String createdBy;

  @Column(name = "updated_at")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  protected Date updatedAt;

  @Column(name = "updated_by", length = 32, nullable = true)
  protected String updatedBy;

  @Column(name = "is_published", columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default 1")
  protected boolean isPublished;

  @Column(name = "is_deleted", columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default 0")
  protected boolean isDeleted;

  // Getters and Setters
}
```

**AbstractBookingEntity.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractBookingEntity extends AbstractJpaEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6980195228404112444L;

  @Column(name = "booking_id", nullable = false)
  protected String bookingId;

  @Column(name = "room_night_booking_id", nullable = false)
  protected String roomNightBookingId;

  public String getBookingId() {
    return bookingId;
  }

  public void setBookingId(String bookingId) {
    this.bookingId = bookingId;
  }

  public String getRoomNightBookingId() {
    return roomNightBookingId;
  }

  public void setRoomNightBookingId(String roomNightBookingId) {
    this.roomNightBookingId = roomNightBookingId;
  }
}
```

**RoomNightEntity.java**

```
@Entity(name = "room_night")
@Table(name = "room_night", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(name = "key_rm_order_sub_order", columnNames = { "booking_id", "room_night_booking_id" }) })
public class RoomNightEntity extends AbstractBookingEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7661960864475909694L;

  @Column(name = "ota_booking_id", nullable = false)
  private String otaBookingId;

  @Column(name = "property_id", nullable = false)
  private Long propertyId;

  @Column(name = "room_type_id", nullable = false)
  private Integer roomTypeId;

  @Column(name = "booking_status", nullable = false)
  private Integer bookingStatus;

  @Column(name = "occupancy", nullable = false)
  private Integer occupancy;

  @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
  private Long userId;

  @Column(name = "payment_mode", nullable = false)
  private String paymentMode;

  @Column(name = "stay_date")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date stayDate;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "roomNightEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private BookingDetailsEntity bookingDetailsEntity;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "roomNightEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private BookingCorporateDetailsEntity bookingCorporateDetailsEntity;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "roomNightEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private BookingDiscountDetailsEntity bookingDiscountDetailsEntity;

  // Getters and Setters
}
```

**BookingCorporateDetailsEntity.java**

```
@Entity(name = "booking_corporate_details")
@Table(name = "booking_corporate_details", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(name = "key_bcd_order_sub_order", columnNames = { "booking_id", "room_night_booking_id" }) })
public class BookingCorporateDetailsEntity extends AbstractBookingEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5577224607005257364L;

  @Column(name = "btc_company")
  private String billToCompany;

  @Column(name = "cr_company_name", nullable = false)
  private String companyName;

  @Column(name = "cr_manager_name")
  private String managerName;

  @Column(name = "cr_manager_email")
  private String managerEmail;

  @Column(name = "cr_manager_phone")
  private String managerPhone;

  @OneToOne(optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "room_night_booking_id", referencedColumnName = "room_night_booking_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private RoomNightEntity roomNightEntity;

  // Getters And Setters
}
```

**BookingDetailsEntity.java**

```
@Entity(name = "booking_details")
@Table(name = "booking_details", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(name = "key_bd_order_sub_order", columnNames = { "booking_id", "room_night_booking_id" }) })
public class BookingDetailsEntity extends AbstractBookingEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -4487373751934892176L;

  @Column(name = "guest_status", nullable = false)
  private int guestStatus;

  @Column(name = "is_vip")
  private boolean isVip;

  @Column(name = "is_walkin")
  private int isWalkin;

  @Column(name = "room_number")
  private String roomNumber;

  @Column(name = "shifted_from")
  private long shiftedFrom;

  @Column(name = "checkin_datetime")
  private Date checkinDateTime;

  @Column(name = "checkout_datetime")
  private Date checkoutDateTime;

  @Column(name = "noshow_datetime")
  private Date noShowDateTime;

  @Column(name = "cancel_datetime")
  private Date cancelDateTime;

  @Column(name = "cancelled_reason")
  private String cancelReason;

  @OneToOne(optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "room_night_booking_id", referencedColumnName = "room_night_booking_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private RoomNightEntity roomNightEntity;

  // Getters and Setters
}
```

**BookingDiscountDetailsEntity.java**

```
@Entity(name = "booking_discount_details")
@Table(name = "booking_discount_details", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(name = "key_bdd_order_sub_order", columnNames = { "booking_id", "room_night_booking_id" }) })
public class BookingDiscountDetailsEntity extends AbstractBookingEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -756417075758184555L;

  @Column(name = "discount", nullable = false)
  private double discount;

  @Column(name = "discount_type")
  private int discountType;

  @Column(name = "coupon_code")
  private String couponCode;

  @OneToOne(optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "room_night_booking_id", referencedColumnName = "room_night_booking_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private RoomNightEntity roomNightEntity;

  // Getters and Setters
}
```

When I execute the get/delete `RoomNightEntity` code, I get the following exception -

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [public java.lang.String com.casa.fabbookingbase.entity.AbstractBookingEntity.roomNightBookingId] by reflection for persistent property [com.casa.fabbookingbase.entity.RoomNightEntity#roomNightBookingId] : 2; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [public java.lang.String com.casa.fabbookingbase.entity.AbstractBookingEntity.roomNightBookingId] by reflection for persistent property [com.casa.fabbookingbase.entity.RoomNightEntity#roomNightBookingId] : 2
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:314)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:436)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.deleteByBookingId(Unknown Source)
at com.casa.fabbooking.service.BookingServiceTest.testDeleteBooking(BookingServiceTest.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringTestMethod.invoke(SpringTestMethod.java:160)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTestMethod(SpringMethodRoadie.java:233)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie$RunBeforesThenTestThenAfters.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:333)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:217)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:197)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:143)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:160)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [public java.lang.String com.casa.fabbookingbase.entity.AbstractBookingEntity.roomNightBookingId] by reflection for persistent property [com.casa.fabbookingbase.entity.RoomNightEntity#roomNightBookingId] : 2
at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:43)
at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:58)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValue(ComponentType.java:414)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:238)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.generateHashCode(EntityUniqueKey.java:67)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.<init>(EntityUniqueKey.java:48)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:679)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:427)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:151)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:125)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1132)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:992)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2610)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2593)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2422)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2417)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1339)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:368)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.getResultList(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$DeleteExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:275)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:82)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field com.casa.fabbookingbase.entity.AbstractBookingEntity.roomNightBookingId to java.lang.Long
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:39)
... 76 more
```

**PS: I am using Spring Data JPA 1.10.7.RELEASE with Hibernate 5.1.0.Final on MySQL 5.7.**

Comment: I guess the reason is you are mapping your roomNightBookingId to a String field in  AbstractBookingEntity.java. Are you sure about this?

Comment: @Dave  Yes. RoomNightBookingId is an alphanumeric id, that's why it's string.

Answer (score 0):

Check `room_night_booking_id` column's type in the table of RoomNightEntity (`room_night` if I can see it correctly.). It should not be number type.

Looks like **Java** tries to resolve class to `Long` and then tries to assign the `Long` to `String` property.

Comment: It's a string type not a number. It's alphanumeric id on which I am trying join

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you "execute the get/delete RoomNightEntity code". Assuming that you are referring to the entity and not the id (e.g. getRoomNightEntity() and not getRoomNightEntityId() - have you tried removing the roomNightBookingId field from AbstractBookingEntity? It looks like you are making two references to roomNightBooking one by id and one by entity while only one is needed. The error message explicitly refers to the field roomNightBookingId (property [...]
RoomNightEntity#roomNightBookingId) which is strange if you call the get/delete entity code. If you do call getRoomNightEntityId() you might want to comment out the entity field/methods in the subclasses just too see what the influence will be.

Could also be a security error according to the docs btw.

Best wishes Marc

Comment: I am calling getRoomNightEntity(). And I haven't tried removing the field from Abstract class but will now try for sure.